# JS - setInterval while looping for array

Tags: javascript, arrays, setinterval

I have an array that it filled with objects that hold a attribute that is either called "move" or "turn" and specify how to animate a image on a canvas.
Upon clicking a button, i want to loop over the array and animate the elements in the correct order, i.e. move the object, turn it, move it again.

This is the code:

```
var animation = false;

this.executePlan = function(){ // part of object
    var self = this //  part of object

    for (var i = 0; i < this.moves.length; i++){
        var move = this.moves[i];

        if (move.type == "move"){
            var path = new Path({x: self.x, y: self.y}, {x: move.x, y: move.y});

            animation = setInterval(function(){
                console.log("move");
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, res, res);
                self.draw();
                self.x += path.vector.x;
                self.y += path.vector.y;
                path.vector.s--;
                    if (path.vector.s <= 0){
                        clearInterval(animation);
                    }
                },
            10);
        }
        else if (move.type == "turn"){
            animation = setInterval(function(){ 
                console.log("turn");                    
                if (move.a > 0){
                    self.facing++;
                    move.a--;
                }
                else {
                    self.facing--;
                    move.a++;
                }
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, res, res);
                ctx.save();
                ctx.translate(self.x, self.y);  
                ctx.rotate(self.facing*Math.PI/180);
                ctx.drawImage(self.img, -self.size/2, -self.size/2, self.size, self.size);
                ctx.restore();
                    if (move.a == 0){
                        clearInterval(animation);
                    }
                },              
            30);
        }
    }
}
```

For the purpose of this example, i have to animate a straight movement path, than a turn, than a straight movement path and im under the impression that the code should hold, i.e.
first array element triggers if clause, second triggers elseif clause, first triggers if clause.

However, what happens is that the various intervall do overlap, which leads to my image moving out of the canvas, while rotating all the time - instead of moving, then rotating and finally moving straight again

How can i fix the code and what exactly is the error ?

thanks,

Comment: Single word answer **CLOSURES**.

Comment: Akshay Khandelwal wat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're starting both/all animations at the same time.

You need some mechanism to start subsequent animations only after the earlier animations are done. My suggestion would be to change your for loop into a function, where each animation is responsible for calling the function again (with an incremented `i`) when its animation is complete.

**EDIT**

An example of the approach I suggested (completely untested):

```
var animation = false;

this.executePlan = function() {
    var self = this;

    function doStep(i) {
        var move = this.moves[i];

        if (move.type == "move") {
            var path = new Path({ x: self.x, y: self.y }, { x: move.x, y: move.y });

            animation = setInterval(function() {
                console.log("move");
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, res, res);
                self.draw();
                self.x += path.vector.x;
                self.y += path.vector.y;
                path.vector.s--;
                if (path.vector.s <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(animation);
                    if (i + 1 < this.moves.length) {
                        doStep(i + 1); // if there's more, do the next step
                    }
                }
            }, 10);
        }
        else if (move.type == "turn") {
            animation = setInterval(function() { 
                console.log("turn");                    
                if (move.a > 0){
                    self.facing++;
                    move.a--;
                }
                else {
                    self.facing--;
                    move.a++;
                }
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, res, res);
                ctx.save();
                ctx.translate(self.x, self.y);  
                ctx.rotate(self.facing*Math.PI/180);
                ctx.drawImage(self.img, -self.size/2, -self.size/2, self.size, self.size);
                ctx.restore();
                if (move.a == 0) {
                    clearInterval(animation);
                    if (i + 1 < this.moves.length) {
                        doStep(i + 1); // if there's more, do the next step
                    }
                }
            }, 30);
        }
    }

    doStep(0); // start the first animation
}
```

Comment: Good answer. One note: your `doStep` function isn't recursive. In fact it would be a problem if it were, since a long series of steps would consume stack space for each call. The function has the _appearance_ of recursion, but that's misleading. Because the nested calls to `doStep` are inside timer callbacks, they are executed after the original `doStep` call returns. So it's really a series of scheduled calls where each one schedules the next, not recursion or reentrancy.

Comment: Thanks. Ill look into this, very much appreciate the example mockup.

Comment: I'm not sure if your definition of "recursive" is too restrictive or not, but perhaps a better wording would be "Write a function which results in that function being called again."

Comment: @MichaelGeary I dropped the word "recursive" to be on the safe side.

Comment: Well, its working. I didnt know i can ust create a new function inside a function like that. Interesting.
Much appreciate your effort. GL HF.

Comment: Just one follow up.
How exactly could i control when to do something once the animations are done ?
Going by control flow, anything that is called after "doStep(0)", even outside of this function (i.e. third function calls executePlan() in the first place will resolve while the animations are being done.
What would be the correct way to "pause" code execution until clearInterval(animation) has been called AND i = self.moves.length ?

Comment: You could just add an `else` clause to those `if` statements, so once the animation is done, if there are no more animations, go do whatever you want to do next.

Comment: Ah, right. I added a callback that happens on else. And it works. Sorry, brainfart. thanks again.